# PHP form submitting every time page is opened/refreshed

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a PHP form that submits every time the page is opened/refreshed. I only want it to submit when the submit button is pressed. I am completely new to PHP so would appreciate any help.

Also, if possible I would prefer the page to not refresh when the submit button is pressed. I'd like to just have a message appear below the button that says something like, thank you for submitting. I have searched for this topic but couldn't understand other answers as they were too vague.

**Here is form.php:**

```js
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_phone = $_POST['cf_phone'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_postcode = $_POST['cf_postcode'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'info@domain.com';
$subject = 'Call back form submission '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'Phone: '.$field_phone."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Postcode: '.$field_postcode."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  print('Thanks, you will receive a call back within the next hour.');
  window.location = 'http://www.domain.com';
 </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to info@domain.com to recieve a call back');
  window.location = 'http://www.domain.com';
 </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

**And here is the HTML:**

```html
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="bat/form.php" method='post'>
                    <div id="container">
  <div id="form1"><div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 input-group-lg">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name='cf_email'>
          </input>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 input-group-lg">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Postcode" name='cf_postcode'>
          </input>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="form2"><div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 input-group-lg">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name='cf_name'>
          </input>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 input-group-lg">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone number" name='cf_phone'>
          </input>
         
        </div>
      </div></div>
</div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 input-group-lg">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" name='cf_message'>
          </input>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-med" value='Submit &raquo;'>
          </input>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Actually what happening that after one time submit when you press agai f5 then it resubmitted? is that the case?

Comment: There are plenty of guides out there on how to solve this issue, you're not the first one to have the issue with the form resubmitting because you're not clearing the data from the header, as for the other part: use Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

you should redirect page with java script and its prevent you from submit the form when you refresh the page

```
echo "<script>window.open('samepage.php' , '_self')</script>";
```

use this code at the end of the parsing of your form request
I think your problem get solved

Comment: Thanks! This worked! Unfortunately it still sends a blank submission email as well as the submitted one. Do you know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <?php
    $field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
    $field_phone = $_POST['cf_phone'];
    $field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
    $field_postcode = $_POST['cf_postcode'];
    $field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

    $mail_to = 'info@domain.com';
    $subject = 'Call back form submission '.$field_name;

    $body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
    $body_message .= 'Phone: '.$field_phone."\n";
    $body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
    $body_message .= 'Postcode: '.$field_postcode."\n";
    $body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

    $headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

    $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

    if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      print('Thanks, you will receive a call back within the next hour.');
      window.location = 'http://www.domain.com';
     </script>
    <?php
    }
    else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to info@domain.com to recieve a call back');
      window.location = 'http://www.domain.com';
     </script>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
 
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
                 <head>
                 <meta charset="utf-8">
                 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                 <meta name="generator" content="HTML Template">
     <title> Test </title>
                 </head>
    <body>


     <form class="form-horizontal" action="bat/form.php" method='post'>
                        <div id="container">
      <div id="form1"><div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10 input-group-lg">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name='cf_email'>
              </input>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10 input-group-lg">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Postcode" name='cf_postcode'>
              </input>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="form2"><div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10 input-group-lg">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name='cf_name'>
              </input>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10 input-group-lg">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone number" name='cf_phone'>
              </input>
             
            </div>
          </div></div>
    </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10 input-group-lg">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" name='cf_message'>
              </input>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-med" value='Submit &raquo;'>
              </input>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>



</body>
</html>
```

Try this

**Save file as .php**